# Does Wagtail template variable "self" exist in (Django) pages that don't subclass Page?

Tags: django, django-models, wagtail

Wagtail newbie here templating a response that is derived from a Django-based `models.Model` class and am noticing that it does have the `{{ page }}` template variable available but not `{{ self }}`.

Just looking for confirmation that the this is because `{{ self }}` template variable is only available to classes that extend `Page`. Not finding anything in the docs about it.

Thanks in advance,
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes - the `self` variable is specific to `Page`. The more accurate answer is that for non-`Page` models, the very idea of a response being 'derived' from the model is a misconception...

An ordinary Django model does not know anything about templates or serving HTTP responses - that behaviour is specific to the Wagtail `Page` model. (More specifically: the `Page` model implements a method `serve(request)` which renders a template that has a certain set of variables available to it, including `page` and `self`.)

If you're following the usual Django conventions, you probably have a view function like this:

```
def show(request, object_id):
    my_page = SomeModel.objects.get(id=object_id)
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {
        'page': my_page,
    })
```

Here, the template response is coming from the call to `render`, and it's entirely up to you which variables you make available on that template. In this case, the variable `{{ page }}` will be available on the template, simply because that's what we passed as the last parameter to `render`. This is entirely independent of anything that happens in `SomeModel` - that model has no influence over the template rendering process.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I get that what goes to the template is whatever gets passed to it. Just trying to verify that `{{ self }}` was coming from the `Page` parent class (and not somewheres else) and that I shouldn't be surprised if it's "missing" from a non-Wagtail response.  Thanks for the illumination/elaboration!